# Django Model Design for Nested Json Output

Tags: json, django, database, model, nested

I would like to design models in order to get json output as below. I've been trying different alternatives, using foreignkey or manytomany fields but couldn't get it worked.

This is what I want to get. Every user may have different trainings and each training for the subject user may have more than one date.

{
  "userid": "12345",
  "username": "John",
  "trainings": {
    "trn1": [
      "20-01-2018"
    ],
    "trn2": [
      "20-01-2018",
      "20-01-2019"
    ],
    "trn3": [
      "20-01-2018",
      "20-01-2019",
      "15-04-2019"
    ]
  },
  "notes": "a note about the user"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the database you are using. Postgres can utilize an `ArrayField` for storing the list of dates. If you are using any other DB you will need aditional model for dates or save them as a JSON list into a TextField. Here are both options:

With Postgres:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField()
    username = models.CharField()


class Training(models.Model):
    trainingid = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='trainings',
    )
    dates = ArrayField(
        models.DateField()
    )
```

With other DBs:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField()
    username = models.CharField()


class Training(models.Model):
    trainingid = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='trainings',
    )

class Date(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    training = models.ForeignKey(
        Training,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='dates',
    )
```

Here is how to recreate your json object for any DB option:

```
users = []
for user in User.objects.all():
    current_user = {
        'userid': user.userid,
        'username': user.username,
        'trainings': {}
    }
    for training in user.trainings:
        current_user['trainings'][training.trainingid] = []
        for date in training.dates:
            current_user['trainings'][training.trainingid].append(date.date)
    users.append(current_user)

json_users = json.dumps(users)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond, I'll try it!